# Как закрыть окно (любой программы), зная его заголовок?

Tags: visual-basic, visual-studio

Как закрыть окно чужой программы, зная его заголовок? У меня были идеи по поводу:

```
AppActivate("Some Window")
SendKeys("%{F4}")
```

Но всё же, мне кажется, что есть способ "поцивильнее". Пишу на Visual Basic в Visual Studio 2010

Comment: Это Visual Basic 6 или Visual Basic.NET?

Comment: Visual Studio, блин, подумайте головой... .net, конечно же!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

На WinAPI, не зависимо от языка и среды разработки:
 1. [FindWindow](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms633499(VS.85).aspx) поиск окна (второй строковой параметр - заголовок окна), можно еще посмотреть [FindWindowEx](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms633500(v=VS.85).aspx)
 2. послать сообщение [WM_QUIT](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms632641(v=VS.85).aspx) функцией [SendMessage](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms644950(v=VS.85).aspx)
еще WM_DESTROY, WM_CLOSE, GetMessage...

Comment: за FindWindow огромное спасибо ^_^ но я вот нашёл функцию интересную DestroyWindow, но она возвращает False, а в GetLastError остаётся ошибка 8623659860619165701

Answer (score 1):

Для VB.6 действовать по инструкции: "[Как закрыть один экземпляр Windows-приложения программным способом](http://support.microsoft.com/kb/176391)". Для VB.NET подход остается тем же, но код нужно изменить, используя Platform Invoke (DllImport и т.п.).

Answer (score 1):

Проблема решена, всем спасибо, все свободны ^.^

Сработало, вот готовая функция:

```
    Private Declare Function SendMessage Lib "User32" Alias "SendMessageA" (ByVal hWnd As IntPtr, ByVal Msg As UInteger, ByVal wParam As Long, ByVal lParam As Long) As Long
    Private Declare Function FindWindow Lib "User32" Alias "FindWindowA" (ByVal lpClassName$, ByVal lpWindowName$) As IntPtr

    Public Function CloseWindowByTitle(ByVal Title$) As SByte
        Dim hW As IntPtr
        Try
            If FindWindow(Nothing, Title) <> Nothing Then
                hW = FindWindow(Nothing, Title)
            Else : Return 0 ' ОКНА НЕТ '
            End If
            If SendMessage(hW, &H10, Nothing, Nothing) Then : Return 1 ' ЗАКРЫЛОСЬ УДАЧНО '
            Else : Return -1 ' ОШИБКА '
            End If
        Catch : Return -1
        End Try

End Function
```

p.s. модеры, отредактируйте пожалуйста код как следует.. в плане оформления =D

Answer (score 0):

А еще можно taskkill-ом убить, верняк полнейший.

Comment: Мне нужно именно окно, а не процесс.

Comment: посмотрите справку: taskkill /?
в вашем случае:
taskkill /F /FI "WINDOWTITLE eq заголовок_окна" /T
Хотя да, в вашем случае может и не пойдет, если у процесса несколько окон, и вам надо закрыть только одно из них.

Comment: За совет, конечно, спасибо. Но для такой цели мне бы и System.Diagnostics.Process хватило. ))